# showAction : finding fe_user entry by username instead of uid

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I created my own (Typo3 6.2) extension with the Extension Builder to extend *fe_users* and all is working fine but I would like to be able to use the *showAction* based on the **username** instead of the **uid** of the user.

The goal is simply to be able to call the controller on the frontend like this:

my.domain.com/users?tx_crilcq_crilcqmember[username]=johndoe&tx_crilcq_crilcqmember[action]=show

instead of this:

my.domain.com/users?tx_crilcq_crilcqmember[member]=2&tx_crilcq_crilcqmember[action]=show

At first I thought that I had to modify the extended repository (class MemberRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository) but it seems that it is used for requests returning an array of entries and not to reference a single instance. Don't know if I'm right about this but my feeling is that the thing I need to modify is somewhere else.

Any clue someone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Extbase repository has magic methods **findBy[property]**, **findOneBy[property]** and **countBy[property]**, that returns/counts objects by the given property.

You can change your show action as shown below:

```
/**
 * @param string $username
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction($username) {
    $user = $this->memberClassRepository->findOneByUsername($username);
    $this->view->assign('user', $user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! These methods will surely be useful.